# Cannot install SASL when I want to install PyHive

Tags: python, c++, hive

When installing PyHive,I found I had to install install SASL. But when I install SASL, I get the following error:

> sasl/saslwrapper.cpp(247) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
>   file: 'stdint.h': No such file or directory
>         error: command 'C:\Users\geekp\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual
>   C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\amd64\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

Can anyone help me to figure it out?

Comment: I want to flush my tun of data into hive,and I am trying pyhive

Comment: The "stable" version of `pyhive` is notoriously broken, even in Anaconda repos. You have to recompile the "latest" SASL libraries to fix that, as you have discovered. And clearly you don't have the skills... So I advise you to install `impyla` instead, it's maintained by Cloudera, and it works out-of-the-box.

Comment: >So I advise you to install impyla instead.

From a look to their github impyla is dependent on sasl if you want it to support Hive. 

https://github.com/cloudera/impyla

Any other solutions? I have the exact same problem.